# Why can't i add data to google maps in a blazor component without running code twice?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have no previous Blazor and very little asynchronous programming experience. I'm exploring using Blazor for a google maps project and trying to add a geojson point to the map using the google maps javascript api. I wasn't sure of the best way to do this, so my plan was to update the inner html of a hidden div in a blazor component and reference that value in my google map api call.
When I call AddMapData (which gets a geojson string from my db) to set the html of the inner div in both OnInitializedAsync and OnAfterRenderAsync everything works great:

```
@page "/map"

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using DataAccessLibrary


@inject IGeoData _db
<div id="info-box"></div>
<div hidden id="mapData">@mapData </div>

<h3>Map</h3>

<div id="map" ></div>


@code {

    private string mapData;
    private List<string> data;

    async Task<bool> AddMapData()
    {
        data = await _db.GetGeoData();
        mapData = data.First<string>();
        mapData = mapData.Substring(1, mapData.Length - 2);
        return true;
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await AddMapData();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await AddMapData();
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initMap", null);
        }
    }
}
```

Why do I have to call AddMapData in both? My first thought was to only call it in the OnAfterRenderAsync override, but the div.innerhtml value is "". Any thoughts or input is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding  StateHasChanged() after AddMapData() in OnAfterRenderAsync. I no longer override OnInitializedAsync.

```
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await AddMapData();
        StateHasChanged();

        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initMap", null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You realize that OnAfterRenderAsync will be called each time the page re-renders. Any change to any other data will hit your DB again. Does it not work to put the AddMapData() in the OnInit and the JSRuntime call in the OnAfterRender?

Comment: @SamuelWarren I did not realize that; however, it did not work because evidently [Blazor doesn't wait for OnInitializedAsync to finish before Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316079/blazor-onafterrenderasync-javascript).  The map would render before the data was loaded to the page and I got a jsinterop error. Thanks to your comment I found that question and implemented something similar to the top answer.