# Failure to display the file of photos saved in byte format as a large photo when clicking on a smaller photo in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In the Blazor project, we have a list of photos that are retrieved and displayed in a loop of these photos, which are stored as bytes in the SQL Server database. These photos are displayed correctly and without problems responsively. The problem is that I can't and don't know how to upload these photos as large photos. I have used several methods, but when I want to open a photo in a new tab, only a blank page is displayed. If possible, if you have a solution for this problem, please send it to me.

```
@using System.Drawing
@using System.IO
@inject IValueMeterLists _iValueMeterLists
@inject ILectureRepository _Lecture
@inject NavigationManager uriHelper

@if (itm == null)
{
    <LoadingSpinner />
}
else
{
    <section class="job_area dashboard_contents p-top-5 p-bottom-10 rtl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="job_detail_module information dark-bg">
                        <h3 class="job__title">@StrComponentTitle</h3>
                        <div class="job__content">
                            <ul class="informations">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-note"></span>
                                        <p>Agent: </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>@itm.AgentFullName</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-tag"></span>
                                        <p>Type Kind : </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p> @itm.ValueMeterListsKind.Name </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-wallet"></span>
                                        <p>Rcpt Code :</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>@itm.Code </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-wallet"></span>
                                        <p>Date :</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>@itm.Moment.ToPersianDateString("yyyy/MM/dd")</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-graduation"></span>
                                        <p>Register Date:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>@itm.RegistMoment.ToPersianDateString("yyyy/MM/dd")</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-badge"></span>
                                        <p>Travel Cost:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>@itm.TravelCost</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
                                        <p>Other Costs:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>@itm.OtherCost</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
                                        <p>Remarks:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>@itm.Remarks</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
                                        <p>--:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>--</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="job_area dashboard_contents p-top-5 p-bottom-10 rtl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="job_detail_module information dark-bg">
                        <h3 class="job__title">Waranty Info</h3>
                        <div class="job__content">
                            <ul class="informations">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-note"></span>
                                        <p>Product Name: </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>@itm.ValueMeter.Product.GoodsName</p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-tag"></span>
                                        <p>Prod Number : </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p> @itm.ValueMeter.ProductSerialNumber </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-wallet"></span>
                                        <p>Earanty Statue :</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p> 
                                            @if (WarInfoStart != null)
                                            {
                                                @WarInfoStart.WarStatus.Name;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <div>UnKnown</div>
                                            }
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-wallet"></span>
                                        <p>Waranty Walidation :</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>
                                            @if (WarInfo != null)
                                            {
                                                @WarInfo.WarStatus.Name;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <div>UnKnown</div>
                                            }
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="info_title">
                                        <span class="icon-graduation"></span>
                                        <p>Waranty End Date:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <p>
                                            @if (WarInfo != null)
                                            {
                                                @WarInfo.EndRepaierWarDate.Value.ToPersianDateString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <LoadingSpinnerLinear></LoadingSpinnerLinear>
                                            }
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    @if (itm.ValueMeterListsFiles != null)
    {
        <section class="event_area p-top-100 p-bottom-100 rtl">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">


                    @foreach (var itms in itm.ValueMeterListsFiles)
                    {
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                            <div class="card_style1">
                                <figure class="card_style1__info">
                                    @*<img src="@ConvertImage(itms.Photo)" alt="Event card thumbnail"> style="width: 400px" *@
                                    <a @onclick="@(() => RunMyJs(Convert.ToBase64String(@itms.Photo)))" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                        <img id="myImg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(@itms.Photo)" style="cursor:pointer;" />
                                    </a>
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <a @onclick="@(() => RunMyJs(Convert.ToBase64String(@itms.Photo)))" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                            <h4> @itms.ValueMeterListsFileType.TypeName </h4>
                                        </a>
                                        @*  <ul class="date_place">
                            <li>
                            <span class="icon-calendar"></span>
                            <p>--</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                            <span class="icon-location-pin"></span>
                            <p> -- </p>
                            </li>
                            </ul>*@
                                    </figcaption>
                                    <!-- end /.figcaption -->
                                </figure>
                                <!-- end /.figure -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- end /.event_card -->
                        </div>


                    }

                </div>
                <!-- end /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- end /.container -->
        </section>
    }
}

@code {
    #region Parameters
    [Parameter]
    public short FiscalYear { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int ValueMeterID { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int ValueMeterListsKindID { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public long ValueMeterListsCode { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public String StrComponentTitle { get; set; }

    public LosacoWeb.Shared.DTOs.ValueMeter.ValueMeterListsMp itm;
    public string ImageBase64;
    LosacoWeb.Shared.DTOs.ValueMeter.WarInfoMp WarInfo;
    LosacoWeb.Shared.DTOs.ValueMeter.WarInfoMp WarInfoStart;
    #endregion

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            itm = await _iValueMeterLists.GetValueMeterLists(FiscalYear, ValueMeterID,
                ValueMeterListsKindID, ValueMeterListsCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            WarInfo = await _Lecture.GetWarantyStatus(itm.ValueMeter.Product.GoodsCode, itm.ValueMeter.ProductSerialNumber);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            WarInfoStart = await _Lecture.GetWarantyStatus(itm.ValueMeter.Product.GoodsCode, itm.ValueMeter.ProductSerialNumber, itm.ValueMeter.ID);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }        
    }

    private void gotopageImage()
    {
        uriHelper.NavigateTo("data:image/gif;base64,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", true);
    }

    public async Task ShoPicture(String Image)
    {
        try
        {
            await uriHelper.NavigateTo(Image);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, I used the following method to display the photo. But I did not reach any result. The photo is displayed in the current tab. But when I add the _blank option to the file selection to display the photo in the new Tab, only a blank page is displayed. Please advise.

```
        private void gotopageImage()
        {
            uriHelper.NavigateTo("data:image/gif;base64,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", true);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `javascript` and html frame to show images that sent as byte to new page. as I used javascript in Blazor page in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73260398/the-reason-why-javascript-is-not-running-on-the-main-page-of-blazer/73262288#73262288).
at first create a `javascript` file and name it shobytefilejs.js. then find `index.html` in `wwwroot` folder. then copy following method into the `js` file.

```
function window_download(datauri) {
    
    var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + datauri + "'></iframe>"
    var x = window.open();
    x.document.open();
    x.document.write(iframe);
    x.document.close();
}
```

Then inject `@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;` in your page or component.
After that, in you Blazor page or Blazor component define a method something like bellow:

```
public async Task RunMyJs(String Image)
{
    try
    {
        await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("window_download", "data:image/gif;base64," + Image);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

finally call your method in you html code like follow:

```
<a @onclick="@(() => RunMyJs(Convert.ToBase64String(@itms.Photo)))" style="cursor:pointer;">
<img id="myImg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(@itms.Photo)" style="cursor:pointer;" />
</a>
```